# Unable to create newsletters

Tags: emails

I am logged in as user/1 and have created a News content type with publishing options as "Use as simplenews newsletter". I believe all the permissions are correct.

When I try to add new content using this content type I see these at the top of the page:

Add this newsletter issue to a newsletter by selecting a newsletter from the select list. To send this newsletter issue, first save the node, then use the "Newsletter" tab.
Set default send options at Administration > Configuration > Web services > Newsletters.
Set newsletter specific options at Administration > Content > Newsletters.

Re: Add this newsletter issue to a newsletter by selecting a newsletter from the select list. To send this newsletter issue, first save the node, then use the "Newsletter" tab.
I cannot see a "select list" on my create news page.

Re: Set default send options at Administration > Configuration > Web services > Newsletters.
I have created a newsletter category called "Ad Hoc"

Re: Set newsletter specific options at Administration > Content > Newsletters.
I have selected the All newsletters option from the dropdown menu. But no newsletters are available at the bottom of the page...

I am unable to get to Configuration > Simplenews as per the readme file.

What am I missing in order to be able to create News (newsletters)?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow is the following:

1. Create category admin/config/services/simplenews
2. Add newsletter node/add/simplenews (Choose category beneath body)
3. go to node/%/simplenews and send it